# Нужна ли запятая в предложении

Tags: пунктуация

Зато теперь знаем кто есть кто и чего стоит

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

Правильно:

***Зато теперь знаем, кто есть кто и чего стоит.***

См. пример из [***"Орфографического словаря русского языка"*:**](http://orthographic.academic.ru/30193/%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE_%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C_%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]